# Currently having an error with youtube-dl in python, any ideas?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, youtube-dl

This is the error I am getting, I tried to see if anyone else had this issue but it was only with other sites other than youtube and there was no fix listed. If needed I can link the python Code as well. This is happening when using a play command on a discord bot using discord.py-rewrite.

```
[youtube:search] query " www.youtube.com/watch?v=5abamRO41fE": Downloading page 1
ERROR: query " www.youtube.com/watch?v=5abamRO41fE": Failed to parse JSON  (caused by JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 904, in _parse_json
    return json.loads(json_string)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 797, in extract_info
    ie_result = ie.extract(url)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 532, in extract
    ie_result = self._real_extract(url)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 3014, in _real_extract
    return self._get_n_results(query, n)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\youtube.py", line 3200, in _get_n_results
    data = self._download_json(
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 893, in _download_json
    res = self._download_json_handle(
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 879, in _download_json_handle
    return self._parse_json(
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\extractor\common.py", line 908, in _parse_json
    raise ExtractorError(errmsg, cause=ve)
youtube_dl.utils.ExtractorError: query " www.youtube.com/watch?v=5abamRO41fE": Failed to parse JSON  (caused by JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "g:\Bots\TestBot\test.py", line 574, in play
    results = ydl.extract_info(f'ytsearch1: {song_search}', download=True)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 820, in extract_info
    self.report_error(compat_str(e), e.format_traceback())
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 625, in report_error
    self.trouble(error_message, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Jimmy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\youtube_dl\YoutubeDL.py", line 595, in trouble
    raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR: query " www.youtube.com/watch?v=5abamRO41fE": Failed to parse JSON  (caused by JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)')); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are using the latest version; see  https://yt-dl.org/update  on how to update. Be sure to call youtube-dl with the --verbose flag and include its complete output.
```

Comment: for `python`, maybe look into pytube (most tutorials say `import pytube` or `import pytube3`, just replace that with `import pytubeX`, and do `pip install pytubeX`)

Comment: Does pytube do the same thing as youtube-dl cause I use ytdl because it downloads just an mp3 file and can search youtube from the imput its given with either key words or with a link